# UART in VHDL testbench

Tags: fpga, vhdl, uart

I have two questions in general:

1. I have this uart vhdl example code from https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59507062

I tried to do a testbench but in the simulation the receiving part is not receiving, it shows UU.

The next code is the uart.hdl

```
    LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY uart IS
    GENERIC(
        clk_freq        :   INTEGER     := 50_000_000;  --frequency of system clock in Hertz
        baud_rate   :   INTEGER     := 19_200;      --data link baud rate in bits/second
        os_rate     :   INTEGER     := 16;          --oversampling rate to find center of receive bits (in samples per baud period)
        d_width     :   INTEGER     := 8;           --data bus width
        parity      :   INTEGER     := 1;               --0 for no parity, 1 for parity
        parity_eo   :   STD_LOGIC   := '0');            --'0' for even, '1' for odd parity
    PORT(
        clk     :   IN      STD_LOGIC;                                      --system clock
        reset_n :   IN      STD_LOGIC;                                      --ascynchronous reset
        tx_ena  :   IN      STD_LOGIC;                                      --initiate transmission
        tx_data :   IN      STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(d_width-1 DOWNTO 0);  --data to transmit
        rx      :   IN      STD_LOGIC;                                      --receive pin
        rx_busy :   OUT STD_LOGIC;                                      --data reception in progress
        rx_error    :   OUT STD_LOGIC;                                      --start, parity, or stop bit error detected
        rx_data :   OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(d_width-1 DOWNTO 0);   --data received
        tx_busy :   OUT STD_LOGIC;                                      --transmission in progress
        tx          :   OUT STD_LOGIC);                                     --transmit pin
END uart;
        
ARCHITECTURE logic OF uart IS
    TYPE        tx_machine IS(idle, transmit);                                      --tranmit state machine data type
    TYPE        rx_machine IS(idle, receive);                                           --receive state machine data type
    SIGNAL  tx_state                :   tx_machine;                                     --transmit state machine
    SIGNAL  rx_state                :   rx_machine;                                     --receive state machine
    SIGNAL  baud_pulse          :   STD_LOGIC := '0';                               --periodic pulse that occurs at the baud rate
    SIGNAL  os_pulse                :   STD_LOGIC := '0';                           --periodic pulse that occurs at the oversampling rate
    SIGNAL  parity_error        :   STD_LOGIC;                                      --receive parity error flag
    SIGNAL  rx_parity           :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(d_width DOWNTO 0);     --calculation of receive parity
    SIGNAL  tx_parity           :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(d_width DOWNTO 0);     --calculation of transmit parity
    SIGNAL  rx_buffer           :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(parity+d_width DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');   --values received
    SIGNAL  tx_buffer           :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(parity+d_width+1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '1'); --values to be transmitted
BEGIN

    --generate clock enable pulses at the baud rate and the oversampling rate
    PROCESS(reset_n, clk)
        VARIABLE count_baud :   INTEGER RANGE 0 TO clk_freq/baud_rate-1 := 0;           --counter to determine baud rate period
        VARIABLE count_os       :   INTEGER RANGE 0 TO clk_freq/baud_rate/os_rate-1 := 0;   --counter to determine oversampling period
    BEGIN
        IF(reset_n = '0') THEN                                          --asynchronous reset asserted
            baud_pulse <= '0';                                              --reset baud rate pulse
            os_pulse <= '0';                                                    --reset oversampling rate pulse
            count_baud := 0;                                                    --reset baud period counter
            count_os := 0;                                                      --reset oversampling period counter
        ELSIF(clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN
            --create baud enable pulse
            IF(count_baud < clk_freq/baud_rate-1) THEN          --baud period not reached
                count_baud := count_baud + 1;                               --increment baud period counter
                baud_pulse <= '0';                                          --deassert baud rate pulse
            ELSE                                                                --baud period reached
                count_baud := 0;                                                --reset baud period counter
                baud_pulse <= '1';                                          --assert baud rate pulse
                count_os := 0;                                                  --reset oversampling period counter to avoid cumulative error
            END IF;
            --create oversampling enable pulse
            IF(count_os < clk_freq/baud_rate/os_rate-1) THEN    --oversampling period not reached
                count_os := count_os + 1;                                   --increment oversampling period counter
                os_pulse <= '0';                                                --deassert oversampling rate pulse      
            ELSE                                                                --oversampling period reached
                count_os := 0;                                                  --reset oversampling period counter
                os_pulse <= '1';                                                --assert oversampling pulse
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;

    --receive state machine
    PROCESS(reset_n, clk)
            VARIABLE rx_count   :   INTEGER RANGE 0 TO parity+d_width+2 := 0;       --count the bits received
            VARIABLE    os_count    :   INTEGER RANGE 0 TO os_rate-1 := 0;              --count the oversampling rate pulses
    BEGIN
        IF(reset_n = '0') THEN                                                              --asynchronous reset asserted
            os_count := 0;                                                                          --clear oversampling pulse counter
            rx_count := 0;                                                                          --clear receive bit counter
            rx_busy <= '0';                                                                     --clear receive busy signal
            rx_error <= '0';                                                                        --clear receive errors
            rx_data <= (OTHERS => '0');                                                     --clear received data output
            rx_state <= idle;                                                                       --put in idle state
        ELSIF(clk'EVENT AND clk = '1' AND os_pulse = '1') THEN                      --enable clock at oversampling rate
            CASE rx_state IS
                WHEN idle =>                                                                        --idle state
                    rx_busy <= '0';                                                                 --clear receive busy flag
                    IF(rx = '0') THEN                                                               --start bit might be present
                        IF(os_count < os_rate/2) THEN                                                   --oversampling pulse counter is not at start bit center
                            os_count := os_count + 1;                                                       --increment oversampling pulse counter
                            rx_state <= idle;                                                                   --remain in idle state
                        ELSE                                                                                    --oversampling pulse counter is at bit center
                            os_count := 0;                                                                      --clear oversampling pulse counter
                            rx_count := 0;                                                                      --clear the bits received counter
                            rx_busy <= '1';                                                                 --assert busy flag
                            rx_state <= receive;                                                                --advance to receive state
                        END IF;
                    ELSE                                                                                    --start bit not present
                        os_count := 0;                                                                      --clear oversampling pulse counter
                        rx_state <= idle;                                                                   --remain in idle state
                    END IF;
                WHEN receive =>                                                                 --receive state
                    IF(os_count < os_rate-1) THEN                                                   --not center of bit
                        os_count := os_count + 1;                                                       --increment oversampling pulse counter
                        rx_state <= receive;                                                                --remain in receive state
                    ELSIF(rx_count < parity+d_width) THEN                                       --center of bit and not all bits received
                        os_count := 0;                                                                      --reset oversampling pulse counter      
                        rx_count := rx_count + 1;                                                       --increment number of bits received counter
                        rx_buffer <= rx & rx_buffer(parity+d_width DOWNTO 1);                   --shift new received bit into receive buffer
                        rx_state <= receive;                                                                --remain in receive state
                    ELSE                                                                                    --center of stop bit
                        rx_data <= rx_buffer(d_width DOWNTO 1);                                 --output data received to user logic
                        rx_error <= rx_buffer(0) OR parity_error OR NOT rx;                 --output start, parity, and stop bit error flag
                        rx_busy <= '0';                                                                 --deassert received busy flag
                        rx_state <= idle;                                                                   --return to idle state
                    END IF;
            END CASE;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
        
    --receive parity calculation logic
    rx_parity(0) <= parity_eo;
    rx_parity_logic: FOR i IN 0 to d_width-1 GENERATE
        rx_parity(i+1) <= rx_parity(i) XOR rx_buffer(i+1);
    END GENERATE;
    WITH parity SELECT  --compare calculated parity bit with received parity bit to determine error
        parity_error <=     rx_parity(d_width) XOR rx_buffer(parity+d_width) WHEN 1,    --using parity
                                '0' WHEN OTHERS;                                                        --not using parity
        
    --transmit state machine
    PROCESS(reset_n, clk)
        VARIABLE tx_count       :   INTEGER RANGE 0 TO parity+d_width+3 := 0;  --count bits transmitted
    BEGIN
        IF(reset_n = '0') THEN                                                              --asynchronous reset asserted
            tx_count := 0;                                                                          --clear transmit bit counter
            tx <= '1';                                                                              --set tx pin to idle value of high
            tx_busy <= '1';                                                                     --set transmit busy signal to indicate unavailable
            tx_state <= idle;                                                                       --set tx state machine to ready state
        ELSIF(clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN
            CASE tx_state IS
                WHEN idle =>                                                                    --idle state
                    IF(tx_ena = '1') THEN                                                       --new transaction latched in
                        tx_buffer(d_width+1 DOWNTO 0) <=  tx_data & '0' & '1';          --latch in data for transmission and start/stop bits
                        IF(parity = 1) THEN                                                         --if parity is used
                            tx_buffer(parity+d_width+1) <= tx_parity(d_width);                  --latch in parity bit from parity logic
                        END IF;
                        tx_busy <= '1';                                                             --assert transmit busy flag
                        tx_count := 0;                                                                  --clear transmit bit count
                        tx_state <= transmit;                                                       --proceed to transmit state
                    ELSE                                                                                --no new transaction initiated
                        tx_busy <= '0';                                                             --clear transmit busy flag
                        tx_state <= idle;                                                               --remain in idle state
                    END IF;
                WHEN transmit =>                                                                --transmit state
                    IF(baud_pulse = '1') THEN                                                   --beginning of bit
                        tx_count := tx_count + 1;                                                   --increment transmit bit counter
                        tx_buffer <= '1' & tx_buffer(parity+d_width+1 DOWNTO 1);            --shift transmit buffer to output next bit
                    END IF;
                    IF(tx_count < parity+d_width+3) THEN                                    --not all bits transmitted
                        tx_state <= transmit;                                                       --remain in transmit state
                    ELSE                                                                                --all bits transmitted
                        tx_state <= idle;                                                               --return to idle state
                    END IF;
            END CASE;
            tx <= tx_buffer(0);                                                             --output last bit in transmit transaction buffer
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;    
    
    --transmit parity calculation logic
    tx_parity(0) <= parity_eo;
    tx_parity_logic: FOR i IN 0 to d_width-1 GENERATE
        tx_parity(i+1) <= tx_parity(i) XOR tx_data(i);
    END GENERATE;
    
END logic;
```

And the testbench is

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity uart_tb is
    GENERIC(
        clk_freq        :   INTEGER     := 50_000_000;  --frequency of system clock in Hertz
        baud_rate   :   INTEGER     := 19_200;      --data link baud rate in bits/second
        os_rate     :   INTEGER     := 16;          --oversampling rate to find center of receive bits (in samples per baud period)
        d_width     :   INTEGER     := 8;           --data bus width
        parity      :   INTEGER     := 1;               --0 for no parity, 1 for parity
        parity_eo   :   STD_LOGIC   := '0');            --'0' for even, '1' for odd parity
    
end uart_tb;

architecture Behavioral of uart_tb is

    component uart
        port(
          clk       :   IN      STD_LOGIC;                                      --system clock
          reset_n   :   IN      STD_LOGIC;                                      --ascynchronous reset
          tx_ena    :   IN      STD_LOGIC;                                      --initiate transmission
          tx_data   :   IN      STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(d_width-1 DOWNTO 0);  --data to transmit
          rx            :   IN      STD_LOGIC;                                      --receive pin
          rx_busy   :   OUT STD_LOGIC;                                      --data reception in progress
          rx_error  :   OUT STD_LOGIC;                                      --start, parity, or stop bit error detected
          rx_data   :   OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(d_width-1 DOWNTO 0);   --data received
          tx_busy   :   OUT STD_LOGIC;                                      --transmission in progress
          tx            :   OUT STD_LOGIC);                                     --transmit pin
        
    end component;
    
          signal clk        :   STD_LOGIC :='0';                                        --system clock
          signal reset_n    :   STD_LOGIC :='1';                                        --ascynchronous reset
          signal tx_ena :       STD_LOGIC := '0';                                       --initiate transmission
          signal tx_data    :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(d_width-1 DOWNTO 0) := "00000000";  --data to transmit
          signal rx         :   STD_LOGIC :='1';                                        --receive pin
          signal rx_busy    :   STD_LOGIC := '0';                                       --data reception in progress
          signal rx_error   :   STD_LOGIC := '0';                                       --start, parity, or stop bit error detected
          signal rx_data    :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(d_width-1 DOWNTO 0) := "00000000"; --data received
          signal tx_busy    :   STD_LOGIC := '0';                                   --transmission in progress
          signal tx         :   STD_LOGIC := '1';                                   --transmit pin
            
          constant clock : time := 100ns;
begin

 uut: uart port map (
        clk => clk,
        reset_n => reset_n,
        tx_ena => tx_ena,
        tx_data => tx_data,
        rx => rx,
        rx_busy => rx_busy,
        rx_error => rx_error,
        rx_data => rx_data,
        tx_busy => tx_busy,
        tx => tx
    );
    
    clock_p :process
    begin
        clk<='0';
        wait for clock/2;
        clk<='1';
        wait for clock/2;
    end process;
    
    stim_proc: process
    begin
           
    WAIT FOR 100 ns;
    tx_ena <= '1';
    tx_data <= "00001111";
    
    WAIT FOR 100 ns;
    rx <='1';
    WAIT FOR 100 ns;
    tx_ena <='0';
    wait for 100 ns;
    --rx_busy <='1';
    end  process;

end Behavioral;
```

And the simulation is this

[image]

I have read man times the uart.hdl but i still cant figure out why is the receive data not shown.

2. I plan to do my own UART code but first i want to succesfully do the previous testbench.

I have noted that in some example codes they oversample the incoming data, and in some other codes they dont, is the oversampling thing really needed?

An example of an uart not oversampled code is this https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/modules/module-uart-serial-port-rs232.html

Comment: Besides not having a reset_n asserted there are a couple of other things wrong in your testbench. With the default generics the clock period for 50 MHz is 20 ns not 100 ns. [tx_busy and tx_ena are for asynchronous handshaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGOuw.jpg) (done with an independently writen testbench and uart.vhdl downloaded from the Digikey link). Note tx is connected to rx.

Answer (score 3):

In your testbench you are not asserting the reset_n signal at all.

You should make reset_n = '0' for several clock cycles, then deassert it to '1' and then continue with the rest of the simulation.

In the current simulation rx_state never receives an initial value and that is why the rx output signals are undefined

Comment: The reset input is low active, so i maintain it in '1'.

Comment: Also, you're going to have to run the simulation for a lot longer than 1000 ns if you want to see a byte transferred at 19.2 kbps.

Comment: @esencia that is exactly my point, you are never asserting reset so the state machine rx_state never gets an initial value, that is the reason all your output signals are undefined

Comment: I already checked that and now it doesnt appear like UU, but rx_Data doesnt shows the tx_data transmitted

Comment: Your testbench is forcing a '1' onto rx. If you want to see the transmitted data on rx, what should you do on your testbench?